# filter by language in KQL/Kusto/Data Explorer

Tags: kql, azure-data-explorer, kusto-explorer

Is it possible to detect the language of a text string using Kusto functions?  I have a dataset that I would like to filter by language.  Ex. English, Spanish etc.

Example:

```
datatable (text:string) ['Bonjour', 'Salam', 'Hallo', 'Neih hou']
```

Desired Outcome:

```
Text        Language  
'Bonjour',  'French',
'Salam',    'Persian',
'Hallo',    'Danish',
'Neih hou', 'Cantonese'
```

Comment: I understand that you have a dataset with two columns with Text and Language If you want to project/filter/sort the output based on the language then you can use any of the predefined functions using (summarize or sort) in your KQL query. If you want KQL to dynamically read the text and display its appropriate language, then it is not possible in KQL.

Comment: The dataset with 2 columns is the desired outcome not the actual dataset.  The starting dataset only has one column with strings that are in different languages.  From reading your reply it looks like KQl doesn't have any language detection built in ... which answers my question.

Answer (score 0):

It's not available out of the box in ADX but if you can run the python plugin on your cluster then you can use a custom script utilizing a library like https://pypi.org/project/fasttext-langdetect/ or https://pypi.org/project/langdetect/